# How to enable OpenCL extensions?

Tags: opencl

I am trying to enable the OpenCL extension `cl_khr_gl_depth_images` to make the following work:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &gl_depthbuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, gl_depthbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, gl_depthbuffer);

...

cl_depth = clCreateFromGLRenderbuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, gl_depthbuffer, &error);
```

At the moment I am getting the following error from the `clCreateFromGLRenderbuffer` call `CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR`.

I added the following lines to the top of my cpp file:

```
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_gl_sharing : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_gl_depth_images : enable
```

But my compiler gives two unknown pragma warnings and I am still getting the `CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR` error.

Am I including the extensions wrong or can one not use depth-renderbuffers in opencl?

**Edit:** My Device is supporting the extensions in question!
**[The specification!](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.2-extensions.pdf#page=115)**

Comment: `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION` are to be used not in c++ but in  OpenCL.

Comment: Thanks but how do I make sure that all my extensions are enabled before C++ code is executed that requieres these extensions? Is it enough to load the file with **clCreateProgramWithSource** before any relvant C++ code?

Answer (score 2):

As [doqtor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4899330/doqtor) already pointed out, put the lines

```c
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_gl_sharing : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_gl_depth_images : enable
```

at the top of your OpenCL C source code and not in your C++ code.

The C++ part of all available extensions is enabled by default and the required functions of the extension are automatically compiled into the executable.